# Consider the proposition $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$, if one were to write it using logical connectives and the set membership predicate how will it be?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

$(((\alpha,\beta)\in f)\land((\alpha,\gamma)\in g))\rightarrow(\beta = \gamma)$ ?

$((\alpha,\beta)\in f)\leftrightarrow((\alpha,\beta)\in g)$ ?

Some other way?

I ask because of this: If $\alpha$ weren't to have an image defined under $f$ (or $g$), if $f(\alpha)$ (or $g(\alpha)$) "didn't exist". will the proposition be true, false or a meaningless statement (only classical logic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have that $f$ and $g$ are at least functional:

$(((\alpha,\beta) \in f) \land ((\alpha,\gamma) \in f)) \to \beta = \gamma$ (And same for $g$)

Then if the functions are total:

$\forall \alpha \exists \beta (\alpha,beta) \in f$ (same for $g$)

then the two definitions you provide end up being the same, or at least they can be derived from each other.

But if you don't necessarily have total functions, then I would treat a claim like $f(\alpha) = g(\alpha)$ as saying that they *are* defined ... I would not consider this claim to be true if both values are undefined. And, given that you don't assume totality, I would then use:

$\exists \beta (((\alpha,\beta) \in f) \land ((\alpha,\beta) \in g))$

in other words: neither of the two, since both would be true if the values would be undefined.

Comment: So in your belief $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ could not be vacuously true? Is that a convention? Would a contradiction arise otherwise?

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for answering :)

Comment: @IDUTDP I am not sure it is a convention .... And I can certainly see some uses for saying that $f(\alpha) = g(\alpha)$ when both are undefined, since with that we can much more easily say that two functions are identical, for example. So, on second thought, maybe the second definition would be fine to use. I would not use the first one though, since that would also hold true when one of the values is defined, and the other is not, and in that case you really don't want to say that the two 'values' are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your insight :)

Comment: @IDUTDP You're welcome! :)